# The "unanswered" tab contains questions with an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The "unanswered" tab contains questions with an answer. Is there anything about the definition of "unanswered" - as used by our site- which that differs from the everyday meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "unanswered question" is defined as a question that has no upvoted or accepted answers (or more precisely no answers with a positive score). Therefore we will see all question that still need a good answer in the unanswered tab.

See:

- [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)